# UNION AND JOING 3 types from same attribute SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following tables

Customer (email, name, address, birthday)
Product (prodID, description, price, weight, type)
Orders (orderID, customer, date, payment)
OrderContent (orderID, product, amount)

the question is

*Find the emails and names of customers who have made at least two orders with different payment methods. List each customer only once.
There are 3 payment method (mobilepay, credit, paypal)*

Can anyone help me with this ?

I have used this code

```sql
SELECT Customer.email, Customer.name
FROM Customer
JOIN Orders
ON Orders.customer=Customer.email
WHERE Orders.payment=("mobilepay")

UNION

SELECT Customer.email, Customer.name
FROM Customer
JOIN Orders
ON Orders.customer=Customer.email
WHERE Orders.payment=("credit")

INTERSECT
SELECT Customer.email, Customer.name
FROM Customer
JOIN Orders
ON Orders.customer=Customer.email
WHERE Orders.payment=("paypal")

UNION

SELECT Customer.email, Customer.name
FROM Customer
JOIN Orders
ON Orders.customer=Customer.email
WHERE Orders.payment=("credit")

UNION 
SELECT Customer.email, Customer.name
FROM Customer
JOIN Orders
ON Orders.customer=Customer.email
WHERE Orders.payment=("paypal")

INTERSECT 
SELECT Customer.email, Customer.name
FROM Customer
JOIN Orders
ON Orders.customer=Customer.email
WHERE Orders.payment=("mobilepay")
```

Comment: thank you, IT is a Homework, My goal is learning and not just get hw done.

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT(DISTINCT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select customer name and email where orders dataset have at least two different payment types.

```
select customer.name, customer.email
from customer customer
cross apply
(
  select count(distinct(orders2.Payment)) PaymentType from orders orders2
  where customer.customerID=orders1.customerID
  group by orders2.Payment
  having(count(distinct(orders2.Payment)))>1
)orders
```

Answer (score 1):

You should study up on both GROUP BY and following it with a HAVING clause which allows you to filter on summarized data.

If you have only the 3 payment methods then there is no need for the Where clause at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) and [count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) to have number of customer having 3 different payment method

By the way, you can replace your big query by some condition in the `WHERE`clause

```sql
SELECT Customer.email, Customer.name
FROM Customer
JOIN Orders
ON Orders.customer=Customer.email
WHERE Orders.payment in ("mobilepay", "credit", "paypal")
```

Note that I don't give you the answer but only some tips

Comment: Don't forget that the HAVING clause is used for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: the join between orders and customer should be customer number

Comment: see (https://www.w3resource.com/mysql-exercises/northwind/products-table-exercises/) join relationship between customers and orders and orders detail